# Split Object array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I've got an object of array like this, i need to split based on total amount, so the first thing is sum total amount, and then split the array based on total amount, if total amount >= 4 they will split and use key of object as new key

```
{
  25: [
    {
      id: 96207,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 1,
      …
    },
    {
      id: 96484,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 1,
      …
    },
    {
      id: 96208,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 2,
      …
    },
    {
      id: 96261,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 1,
      …
    },
    {
      id: 96367,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 1,
      …
    },
    {
      id: 96431,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 4,
      …
    },
    {
      id: 96432,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 1,
      …
    },
    {
      id: 96483,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 1,
      …
    },
    {
      id: 96515,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 2,
      …
    },
    {
      id: 96536,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 1,
      …
    },
    {
      id: 96560,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 1,
      …
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to split it into like this based on amount if total amount >= 4

```
{
  25: [
    {
      id: 96207,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 1,
      …
    },
    {
      id: 96484,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 1,
      …
    },
    {
      id: 96208,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 2,
      …
    }
  ]
},{
  25: [ 
    {
      id: 96261,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 1,
      …
    },
    {
      id: 96367,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 1,
      …
    },
    {
      id: 96432,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 1,
      …
    },
    {
      id: 96483,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 1,
      …
    }
  ]
}, {
  25: [
    {
      id: 96431,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 4,
      …
    }
  ]
}, {
  25: [
    {
      id: 96515,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 2,
      …
    },
    {
      id: 96536,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 1,
      …
    },
    {
      id: 96560,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 1,
      …
    }
  ]
}
```

How can i get the result like that?

Comment: The first item of the desired array has a total amount of 5, which makes it unclear to me.

Comment: Sorry already edited

Comment: I can't see the pattern, what's the grouping logic? I see that each group contains no more than 4 item, but how come some got 1 some got 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have four items in your result instead of five, so it's possible that you intend to merge the items after splitting to minimalize the number of elements you may have, but I will provide you a "naturalistic" solution, that does not mess with the order of items, nor merges them, but does the splitting. If you need anything further, let me know:

```js
let input = {
  25: [
    {
      id: 96207,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 1,
    },
    {
      id: 96484,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 1,
    },
    {
      id: 96208,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 2,
    },
    {
      id: 96261,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 1,
    },
    {
      id: 96367,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 1,
    },
    {
      id: 96431,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 4,
    },
    {
      id: 96432,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 1,
    },
    {
      id: 96483,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 1,
    },
    {
      id: 96515,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 2,
    },
    {
      id: 96536,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 1,
    },
    {
      id: 96560,
      name: "Client Name",
      phone: "123456789",
      amount: 1,
    }
  ]
};

let output = [];

for (let key in input) {
    let amount = 0;
    let obj = [];
    for (let item of input[key]) {
        if ((amount + item.amount > 4) && (obj.length)) {
            output.push({[key]: obj});
            obj = [];
            amount = 0;
        }
        amount += item.amount;
        obj.push(item);
    }
    if (obj.length) output.push({[key]: obj});
}

console.log(output)
```